# teardown of a singleton class in pytest

Tags: python, singleton, pytest

I have a singleton class I'm using in the application (Singleton is implemented in metaclass)

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__instance = None
        super(Singleton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.__instance is None:
            self.__instance = super(Singleton, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return self.__instance
        else:
            return self.__instance


class ApplicationContext(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def __init__(self, db):
        pass
```

Now I want this object to be in a py.test context - but I want it out of the way in some tests. 
I tried to create a teardown function but it didn't seem to work...

```
@pytest.fixture
def context(db, request):
    _context = ApplicationContext(db)

    def teardown():
        print 'teardown'
        del _context   #this is not working. What should be done here?

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return _context
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to say what you mean with:

> Now I want this object to be in a py.test **context** - but I want it **out of the way** in some tests.

Since we're talking about a singleton, I assume you want the fixture to be available, but not **effective** in all tests. In that case, Pytest fixtures can have a [scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session), quoting the relevent part form the docs:

> Fixtures requiring network access depend on connectivity and are usually time-expensive to create. Extending the previous example, we can add a scope="module" parameter to the @pytest.fixture invocation to cause a smtp_connection fixture function, responsible to create a connection to a preexisting SMTP server, to only be invoked once per test module (the default is to invoke once per test function). Multiple test functions in a test module will thus each receive the same smtp_connection fixture instance, thus saving time. Possible values for scope are: function, class, module, package or session.

So in your case I'd assume the (default) scope of `function` should do what you want: the fixture is available in the module (scope), but you have to explicitly use it in each function (out of the way).

Maybe I got your question wrong, but an alternative approach could be to [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) the Singleton in your `ApplicationContext` in your fixture.